# Как зациклить сервер на приём?

Tags: java

Добрый день, есть сервер

```
public class Server_main implements Runnable {


     private ServerSocket server; 
     private Socket client;

    /*****************STREAM*****************/
    static private BufferedOutputStream output;
    static private BufferedInputStream input;
    /***************************************/


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        new Thread (new Server_main()).start();


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192]; 
        int in;

        try {

            server= new ServerSocket(60000/*номер порта*/, 10/*колличество подключений*/);
            client= server.accept();
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:/"));
            input = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            while ((in = input.read(byteArray)) != -1){
                output.write(byteArray,0,in);           

                }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           
}
```

который после приёма файла прекращает работу. После этого его нужно снова запускать в ручную. Вопрос в том где в коде прописать цыкл на его не прерывную работу ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый простой способ будет вот так:

```
server = new ServerSocket(60000/*номер порта*/, 10/*колличество подключений*/);
while (true) {
    client= server.accept();
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:/"));
    input = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());

    while ((in = input.read(byteArray)) != -1){
        output.write(byteArray,0,in);           
    }
 }
```

Однако, стоит отметить, что это очень грубый подход.  Гораздо лучше будет  обрабатывать соединение в отдельном треде, что-то типа

```
server = new ServerSocket(60000/*номер порта*/, 10/*колличество подключений*/);
while (true) {
    client = server.accept();
    new ClientThread(client).start();
}
```

И отдельно:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;

    public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        File out = File.createTempFile("mysrv", ".dat", new File("D:/"));

        output = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
        input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];
        int in;
        while ((in = input.read(byteArray)) != -1){
            output.write(byteArray,0,in);           
        }
    }
}
```

Естественно, неоходимо ловить ошибки.  И еще хорошо бы лимитировать количество клиентов, которые могут подсоединяться одновременно - но основная идея, надеюсь, ясна.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, точно, спасибо

Comment: спасибо, заработало со вторым способом только тут же появился другой вопрос так как сервер крутится постоянно те файлы что я на него загрузил не возможно удалить пишет что они используются, пони маю что цыкл надо условие задать, но какое ?

Comment: @VargSieg Ну это понятно - ведь именно это в коде и есть.  Есть несколько способов с этим работать.  Один из вариантов - смотреть, какие данные получены через сокет.  Если конкретная комманда, то организовать остановку.  Либо через какой-нибудь другой тред останавливать тред сервера.

Comment: @VargSieg ну крутите его до определенного условия.. Например если юзер послал ключевое слово `exit` или еще как душе угодно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Спасибо)

Comment: @Aleks G Спасибо)